# Fusion chart : how Vertical Line on Dataplot when mouse hover to Dataplot

Tags: fusioncharts

Is it possible to show Vertical Line on Dataplot when mouse hover to Dataplot in multiseries 2d or 3d chart?

or 
can we show Vertical lines for each dataplot in multiseries 2d or 3d chart?

My Fusion chart Version is 3.3.1.

Comment: AFAIK, that is not quite possible to do. Can you give more info about your application regarding why would you need to do that?

Comment: ok. i have changes my chart type to MSLine.swf. in MSCOmbie 3D, there are no attribues available for VDIVLINES.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to show vertical Line on each dataplot when mouse is hovered over the plot in Multi-series charts.

However, it is possible to show vertical lines for each data plot when the chart is rendered. It looks like you want to separate one MS dataplot from the other. You may use "vLine" available in all MS charts (except Zoom Line chart where it is vTrendlines).

vLines are vertical separator lines that help you separate blocks of data. These lines run through the height of the chart, thereby segregating data into different blocks.

These vertical lines are placed between category elements. Refer : http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/AttDesc/VLines.html

Comment: yes, i tried that. but my multiseries chart render as line. so if add vLine, my lines are not displayed. only Dataplots will displayed there. so i am not ablr to add vertical line in multiseries chart any how.

Comment: The Flash variant of MSCombi3D chart does not support vLines. Try JS charts. To convert your existing flash chart to JS chart, you need to add this line before chart rendering:  FusionCharts.setCurrentRenderer('JavaScript');

Comment: yes. i am not using flash charts. i am always using javascript charts.

Comment: Then you should be able to see the vLines. Pass your XML/JSON data for me to check it.